# Using wp_tag_cloud with only current post tag with special class

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I am trying to output all the tags (custom taxonomy) without link, and add special class to current post tags.
For example: if there are 10 tags but current post has 3 of them applied, then it should display all the 10 tags without link but only 3 tags should have special class.

I am currently using:

```
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );
        $tag_list = implode(',', wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id') );
        wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax, 'include' => $tag_list) );
```

which is just showing tags with link for current post.

Comment: Just want to update my question, but don't know how to do it.

I want to display all the tags without link, but hightlight (add special class or span) to tags for current post.

Comment: Use the [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/189584/edit) link, left-hand side, bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you trace the code through the source, you will notice that the links are created by `get_term_link()` and that there is a filter in that function called `term_link`. The second parameter of that filter contain the object ID which, as near as I can tell, is only set if the tag is part of the current post. Leveraging that information:

```
function term_link_wpse_189584($termlink, $term) {
//   var_dump($termlink, $term, $taxonomy);
  if (!isset($term->object_id)) {
    $termlink = 'PULL';
  }
  return $termlink;
}
add_filter('term_link','term_link_wpse_189584',10,2);

function tag_cloud_wpse_189584($return) {
  $pat = '|<a.*PULL[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|';
  $return = preg_replace($pat,'$1',$return);
  return $return;
}
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud','tag_cloud_wpse_189584');

$tax = 'post_tag';
wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by following code:

```
        $allterms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
        $pterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy);
        $tag_list = implode(',', wp_list_pluck($pterms, 'term_id') );
        $t = explode(',', $tag_list);
        echo '<div class="tag-cloud">';
        foreach ($allterms as $term)
        {
            if (in_array($term->term_id, $t))
            {
                echo '<span class="stag active">'.$term->name.'</span>';
            }
            else
            { echo '<span class="stag inactive">'.$term->name.'</span>'; }
        }
        echo '</div>';
```